# How to convert the chromosome position for insertions/deletions to rsIDs in a GWAS summary statistics?

Tags: sequence-alignment, gwas

I am trying to convert chromosome positions to rsIDs of a GWAS summary statistics file. I used `bedtools intersect` to merge the reference genome GRCh37 and the summary statistics based on the same chromosome positions.

But, INDELs regions resulted in several rsIDs. Some regions counting +1 base pairs regions resulted in duplicate rsIDs. In some cases, a single SNP related to many positions were not included in the summary statistics file.

I used this command `intersectBed -sorted -a sumstats.bed -b 00-All.vcf -wb` but it did not work. Please let me know if anybody who had a similar experience and solved it before.